# JQuery plugin multiple instance fires twice

Tags: jquery, plugins, jquery-plugins

I have a html form as follows-

```
 <form>
    <button id="btn1">Save & Add</button>
    <button id="btn2">Save & Return</button>
 </form>
```

Those buttons are bound with my jquery plugin as following-

```
 $('#btn1').SwiftSave({ exit: false }, null, null, null, null, null);
 $('#btn2').SwiftSave({ exit: true  }, null, null, null, null, null);
```

This is my plugin-

```
(function ($) {

    $.fn.SwiftSave = function (options,validationRules, onBeforeSend, onSuccess, onError, onComplete) {

           return this.each(function () {

            var $This = $(this);

            var settings = $.extend({
               ....
            }, options);

            var $Form = $This.parents('form');
            $This.on('click', function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $Form.submit();
            });

            //This event fires twice
            $Form.on('submit', function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                event.stopPropagation();
                SubmitFormAsAuto();                    
            });

            function SubmitFormAsAuto() {
                var $SeriallizedData = $Form.serialize();         
                $.ajax({....});
            }
        });
    };
}(jQuery));
```

The problem is, the form is being submitted twice. I checked button click event. It fires normally. Problem is elsewhere.

Perhaps, form.on('submit' ...) has been binded with $Form variable twice.

What did I wrong here?

Comment: Where are you checking `options` which defines exit of true or false? I believe, since you aren't checking that, its submitting for both the buttons and hence may be twice??

Comment: @MilanChheda do you want me to post here 1000 lines of that plugin?

Comment: Nothing in code shown would produce that behavior. Provide a [mcve]

Comment: @ charlietfl I think this post has enough insights to think about the problem. And should not be closed.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your click event fires twice as it is bounded to the buttons twice
Try this code

```
$This.off('click'),on('click', function (event) {
```

instead of

```
$This.on('click', function (event) {
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried your solution. But still it fires twice.

Comment: Button click event triggers normally. Problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Does your page reloads twice